# Only catching outer PatternMatchFail exceptions

Tags: haskell

Given a partial function, e.g.:

```
foo :: Maybe (Bool, a) -> a
foo = \(Just (b, a)) -> (\True -> a) b
```

Is there a way to capture `PatternMatchFail` exceptions thrown by the outermost lambda without capturing `PatternMatchFail` exceptions thrown by the body of the lambda?

```
 ghci> catchingOuterPatternMatchFailure foo (Just (True, ()))
 Right ()
 ghci> catchingOuterPatternMatchFailure foo (Just (False, ()))
 *** Exception: ...: Non-exhaustive patterns in lambda
 ghci> catchingOuterPatternMatchFailure foo Nothing
 Left "...: Non-exhaustive patterns in lambda"
```

I think I'd need something weaker than weak normal head form, only check that the given function pattern matches the given value, not that it does so successfully.

Comment: This looks as a terrible idea. Pattern matching should always be exhaustive. Intentionally causing errors and then trying to catch and fix them later seems more complex. Further, exceptions can only be caught inside IO, greatly limiting this approach. Why do you want to do this? It looks like an XY problem.

Comment: Mocking up [an idea I had last month](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/bjpfda/matching_eithers_using_lambdacase_and_operators/ema9kwu). The proper implementation may require function types that mention their patterns (e.g. `\True-> () :: Partial '[True] Bool ()`)

Comment: I think the [`total`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/total-1.0.5/docs/Lens-Family-Total.html) library does something like that.

Comment: If there was a way to catch the  exception of the outermost lambda, then `f` and `f \`seq\` (id . f)` would behave differently, but with `-O1` or `-O2` the latter will be optimised to the former (We need the `seq`, because `undefined` and `id . undefined` actually do behave differently).